Create A stacked bar plot in facetgrid
I would like to plot using seaborn and pandas. The dataframe is below.
d = {'cutoff': ['>6']*8+ ['>7']*8 +['>8']*8,
     'month': ['3m','3m','3m','3m','6m','6m','6m','6m'] * 3,
     'outcome': ['D','D','I','I']*6,
     'count': ['0','>0']*12,
     'proportion': [0.25, 0.75, 0.4, 0.6, 0.3, 0.7, 0.8, 0.2, 0.1, 0.9, 0, 1.0,
                    0.15, 0.85, 0.2, 0.8, 0.3, 0.7, 0.8, 0.2, 0.35, 0.65, 1.0, 0]}

tdf = pd.DataFrame(d)

I would like to show that by using different cutoffs, in different months, different outcome have different proportions of count. I would like to create a facetgrid and create a stacked bar plot. The plot should look like below,
        >6                                >7                          >8
|                            |                             |
|  xx          xx            |    x   x   x   x            |
|  xx          xx            |    I   x   x   x            |
|  Ix          xI            |    I   I   x   x            |
|  II          xI            |    I   I   x   X            |
|  II          II            |    I   I   I   X            |    
|__II__________II___________ |____I___I___I___I_________   |____________________
   DI          DI               3m,D 3m,I 6m,D 6m,I
   3m          6m

I use the below code.
    def draw_stacked_bar(*args, **kwargs):
        data = kwargs.pop('data')
        ax = plt.gca()  

        pivot_df = data.pivot(index=['month','outcome'], columns='gitis_count', values='proportion')
        pivot_df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, ax=ax)

        plt.xticks(rotation=45)

    g = sb.FacetGrid(grouped_df, col='cutoff', col_wrap=3, height=4, sharey=True)
    g.map_dataframe(draw_stacked_bar)  

But instead, I create an evenly distributed bar in the second grid (>7). Any one can help me to modify it?

Changing grouped_df to tdf and columns='gitis_count' to columns='count', I obtain the following plot. What do you want different?

I wonder if it is possible to make the intra-groups (those with 3m and those with 6m) stay closer and the inter-group (3m vs 6m) separate further.

With pivot_df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, width=0.95, ax=ax) the intra-group distance would get much closer compared to the inter-group distance. You can also call ax.set_xlim(-0.6, len(pivot_df) + 0.6) to have more whitespace inside each subplot.
